# SQL pivoting a CTE(common table expression)

Tags: sql, excel, pivot

I am trying to export data from my SQL DB to Excel, displaying the tables parent-child tree and its relations by defining them as levels. I have this CTE that generate levels:

```
WITH CategoryHierarchy AS (
                    SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, 0 AS Level
                    FROM [Categories]
                    WHERE Id IN (24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37)

                    UNION ALL

                    SELECT c.Id, c.Name, c.ParentId, ch.Level + 1
                    FROM [Categories] AS c
                    INNER JOIN CategoryHierarchy AS ch ON c.ParentId = ch.Id
                    )
                    SELECT * FROM CategoryHierarchy ORDER BY Level asc
```

The result I get is this:

[image]

As you can see, the rows where the ParenId is NULL are the "base" and then it creates levels based on the entries respective parents. The levels are dynamic, currently I have 4 levels but there could potentially be more.

I need to export the contents of this table to an Excel file which should look like this, where we have "-" if there are no corresponding entries to that row.

[image]

I think my best option here is to use the PIVOT-functionality, but I don't know how to accomplish this in the best way. If you have any other options or suggestions I am all ears. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data, only paste in text. How many levels do you need?

Comment: Sorry, I will keep that in mind. As I wrote, the levels are dynamic, currently there are 4 levels, but there can be more rows added that have level 4 entries as parents, they would be level 5-entries and so on.